# how to increment or decrement 2 labels depends on the stepper action in tavleview cell

Tags: swift, xcode

how can to increment the 2 labels inside the tableview cell or decrement depends on the stepper action.
the image below shows all the code that i write

```
import UIKit

class AnimalsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var animalImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var animalTitle: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var animalPrice: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var animalCount: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var stepperCount: UIStepper!
    
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    @IBAction func stepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper)
    {
        // how to increment or decrement depends if the user pressed + or -
        
        // increment the price of the label (animalPrice) by for example 10 or decrement it
        
        // increment the counter of the label (animalCount) by 1 or decrement it by 1
    }
    

}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource
{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
    
    let animals = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tiger") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cat") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lion") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dog")]      //randoms images
    
    let animalTitle = ["tiger" , "cat" , "lion" , "dog"]    //random animals names
    
    let animalWeight = ["20kg" , "10kg" , "20kg" , "25kg"]   //random weight
    
    let animalPrice = ["20$" , "30$" , "40$" , "60$"]   //random price
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        tableView1.dataSource = self
        tableView1.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 115
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        animals.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AnimalsTableViewCell
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try the code and do the same thing with **animalCount**

Comment: Apart from the issue you have to update the data model otherwise you run into unexpected behavior when the user scrolls. And never use multiple arrays as data model. That's very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to write something like

```
yourLabel.text = "\(Your updated score)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 @IBAction func stepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper){
        var price = Int(animalPrice.text ?? "") ?? 0
        
        sender.value == 1.0 ? (price = price + 10) : (price = price - 10)

        self.animalPrice.text = "\(price)"
        
        sender.value = 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//Stepper Action

When you increase/decrease steeper, Price/Count will be increased/decreased as accordingly.

//Set these two properties for UIStepper

stepperCount.minimumValue = 0
stepperCount.maximumValue = 10

```
@IBAction func stepperPressed(_ sender: UIStepper) {

    let selectedValue = Int(sender.value) //Getting stepper current value  
    animalCount.text = "\(selectedValue)"
    
    if let intAnimalPrice = Int("20$".replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")) {

        animalPrice.text = "\(Int(selectedValue) * intAnimalPrice)"
    }
}
```